# Can't resolve 'crypto-js' in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, encryption, docker-compose, cryptojs

I trying to use [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) in react typescript run with docker compose , but I am getting the following error

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto-js' in '/app/crypto'

Here is that i imported crypto-js. For example:

```
import crypto from 'crypto-js';

export const encrypt = (key: string, evalue: any) => {
    const secret_key = crypto.SHA256(key);
    return crypto.AES.encrypt(evalue, secret_key).toString();
};
```

I have tried many times but it is not working.

Comment: Could you show us your `tsconfig` file please? And also, are you already using other node_modules in your project?

Comment: Yes, Here is my tsconfig file:
```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your `tsconfig.json` file, I believe it is because you are specifing `"include": [ "src" ]` so it means that all `node_modules` will be skipped. 
Try removing it and using `baseUrl` option instead.

The types are not required for the project to build (unless you use the `strict` flag). But as @Kael said, it could be useful installing them. So you can specify

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

in your config file

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still got the same error: `Failed to compile
./src/components/crypto/crypto.ts
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto-js' in '/app/src/components/crypto'`

Answer (score 1):

This is late but, may help someone.
You need to install both:

```
npm i crypto-js --save
npm i @types/crypto-js --save
```

[Check documentation at](https://logfetch.com/next-js-encrypt-url-parameter-ids-crypto-js/)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is Typescript requires some type definitions for the packages.

Try to run `npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev`

Comment: Hmm... you may try to stop the development server, delete node_modules and reinstall

Comment: Is your docker image mapped with a volume on your local env? If it is not the case, it could be that your node_modules were just not installed :)

Comment: Manage node_modules packages with docker is always a pain for me honestly

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring in your types.d.ts

```
declare module 'crpyto-js' {
}
```

If that works, we now at least that your TypeScript settings should be correct.

Then you just have to install the `@types/crypto-js` package and delete your module declaration again.
If that doesn't work your typescript config doesn't your node_modules/@types folder.

Then set in your tsconfig.json your TypeRoots

```
  "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings", "node_modules/@types"]
   }
}
```